# How can I change the default storage engine in phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, phpmyadmin

I use InnoDB almost exclusively in my applications. However, if I'm not careful when setting up the table, I forget to change it and phpmyadmin sticks me with MyISAM.  Is there a way to change the default storage engine?

Comment: Maybe it's not so much about PHPMyAdmin but MySQL directly. Have you tried this: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286813/how-to-set-default-storage-engine-innodb-in-xampp-for-linux1-7-3a

Comment: It is possible by doing these steps: navigate to > phpmyadmin -> more -> variables -> storage engine and change it MyISAM to InnoDB.

Comment: @user21380: that's where you can ONLY see what engine MySQL is using.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to add the line `default-storage-engine = InnoDB` under the `[mysqld]` section of your mysql config file (my.cnf or my.ini depending on your operation system) and restart the mysqld service.

I don't believe you can change this through PhpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

This answer is kind of late, but it might help others. If you are afraid to mess something up on the MySQL server, you can change the default engine when creating a table from phpMyAdmin. The default select creator for MySQL engines is this function under `StorageEngine.class.php` in `libraries` folders (in phpMyAdmin 3.5.8.2):

```
<?php
/**
 * returns HTML code for storage engine select box
 *
 * @param string  $name                    The name of the select form element
 * @param string  $id                      The ID of the form field
 * @param string  $selected                The selected engine
 * @param boolean $offerUnavailableEngines Should unavailable storage engines be offered?
 *
 * @static
 * @return  string  html selectbox
 */
static public function getHtmlSelect($name = 'engine', $id = null,
  $selected = null, $offerUnavailableEngines = false)
{
    $selected   = strtolower($selected);
    $output     = '<select name="' . $name . '"'
        . (empty($id) ? '' : ' id="' . $id . '"') . '>' . "\n";

    foreach (PMA_StorageEngine::getStorageEngines() as $key => $details) {
        // Don't show PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA engine (MySQL 5.5)
        // Don't show MyISAM for Drizzle (allowed only for temporary tables)
        if (! $offerUnavailableEngines
            && ($details['Support'] == 'NO'
            || $details['Support'] == 'DISABLED'
            || $details['Engine'] == 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA')
            || (PMA_DRIZZLE && $details['Engine'] == 'MyISAM')
        ) {
            continue;
        }

        $output .= '    <option value="' . htmlspecialchars($key). '"'
            . (empty($details['Comment'])
                ? '' : ' title="' . htmlspecialchars($details['Comment']) . '"')
            . (strtolower($key) == $selected || (empty($selected) && $details['Support'] == 'DEFAULT')
                ? ' selected="selected"' : '') . '>' . "\n"
            . '        ' . htmlspecialchars($details['Engine']) . "\n"
            . '    </option>' . "\n";
    }
    $output .= '</select>' . "\n";
    return $output;
}
```

This select is populated from the following query:

```
SHOW STORAGE ENGINES
```

The following code is selecting the default engine set by MySQL config file:

```
(empty($selected) && $details['Support'] == 'DEFAULT')
```

However, we can change it to make it select InnoDB as the default engine:

```
(empty($selected) && $details['Engine'] == 'InnoDB')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `information_schema`.`GLOBAL_VARIABLES` 
SET `VARIABLE_VALUE`="InnoDB" 
WHERE `VARIABLE_NAME`="DEFAULT_STORAGE_ENGINE"
```

Comment: database: information_schema

Answer (score 1):

You can change it in PHPMYADMIN for each table:

1. Click on the table in phpmyadmin
2. Click "**Operations**" on the top right.
3. In the Table Options section choose your **storage engine** in the drop down menu eg **InnoDB** etc
4. Click **GO**

If you have many tables it may take some time to click in each one and do this but it is possible.

Comment: That doesn't answer the original question though.

Answer (score 1):

**Its an old question but is needed every time for beginners or other peoples
this is a good way that I found and worked:**

The easiest way to change the default engine is to **log on phpMyAdmin** and then go to **Variables >> storage engine** (Variables tab works with WAMP.. for XAMPP find it in Operations tab)

**click edit** and type **InnoDB**.

the default storage engine is now InnoDB

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_storage_engine

=========================================================

main answer link:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/21158741/8934351